# Java GUI App - Overlay Images on a Map (background image)

Tags: java, image, user-interface, dictionary, overlay

I want to create a simple GUI application that displays a map of a city.

I then want to programatically add items (assets) such as hotels, restaurants to this map as images.

**Pseudo-Code** would be as follows

```
[set up background object with map image covering entire form]

[create hotel1 object (image, label with icon or whatever]
hotel1.image = "hotel.png";
hotel1.size-x = 30;
hotel1.size-y = 30;
hotel1.location-x = 450; (pixels)
hotel1.location-y = 300;
background-object.add(hotel1);

[create restaurant1 object (image, label with icon or whatever]
restaurant1 .image = "hotel.png";
restaurant1 .size-x = 30;
restaurant1 .size-y = 30;
restaurant1 .location-x = 600; (pixels)
restaurant1 .location-y = 400;
background-object.add(restaurant1);

[repeat for hotel2, hotel3, restaurant2 etc...]
```

This way I could add any number of Assets to the map. The other functions I would require are

- change the image of an asset (e.g. to show different image for an asset)
  `hotel1.image = "hotel_closed.png";`
- overlap assets (if they are close together)
- register a click event handler for each asset
- change visibility of asset
  `hotel1.visible = false;`

I am an experienced .Net programmer. This task would be a simple one in .Net, however I am not clear on the best way to accomplish the above in Java.  Please could someone suggest the best approach to achieving the above. I am happy to Google if a concept is suggested (I don't need a full coded solution!!)

Many thanks, Ian

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers. I used bits from each answer (sorry, onebeartoe, I avoided JavaFX in the end), but answer goes to MadProgrammer for wealth of information on the topic. (my solution was my comment to MadProgrammer's post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of places you could start, without knowing the entire requirements (ie if you need to download the maps, tile the maps etc), I can only give you a few overview suggestions

I'd start by having a read through (in no particular order)

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Custom Painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)

I'd also make my self familiar with [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

While most of the above are GUI specific, I'd be reading through things like

- [Essential classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html)
- [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Simply because it doesn't matter where you code in Java, these will always be useful.

Happy readings :)

**UPDATE**

Oh, and of course, the all important [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) (AKA JavaDocs)

**UPDATE**

When you're reasonable comfortable with all that, you might like to check out [SwingX WS](http://java.net/projects/swingx-ws), it has a great example of pulling Google & OpenStreet Maps

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. I've kept the requirements nice and simple. It will be a JPG as the map background, resourced locally and set the same size as the form (800px^2). The main issue in front of me appeared to be overlapping images and placing them on the form at a given set of co-ordinates. I have read through the pages you have linked to above...

Comment: ...It looks like the best way to accomplish this is to have a JLayeredPane within a JFrame, then add a JPanel for the background image, then add a smaller JPanel for each of the assets on the map (with a BufferedImage drawn on the JPanel instance), positioned on the JLayeredPane using xPos & yPos. What do you think to this solution?

Comment: Also, re your second update, the map will be a specialised one, so can't source from G.maps or similar. the background .PNG will be fine!

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you want your application to be desktop rather than web based.  In which case I have done something similar (though rather more complicated) before using a third party mapping solution.  Unfortunately that solution required a licence and is no longer available anyway.

If you just want a simple non-scrollable map in a desktop application I suggest you start with a Swing solution.  Look at extending the JComponent object and override the method

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    // use g to draw things
}
```

Use the graphics object to paint your map image and your icons.  Add this Component to your Swing JFrame and set up the correct sizes and layouts.

If you want this in a webpage then someone else would be better placed to help you.

Edit:

From the feedback given here and in the other post I think you may benefit from a slice of code so here goes:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwingPaintDemo extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage map = null;
    private BufferedImage pointer = null;

    public SwingPaintDemo() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        loadImagesFromFile(); 
    }

    private void loadImagesFromFile() {
        // load your images form file - these are fakes: 
        map = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        pointer = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

        Graphics g = map.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

        g = pointer.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // paint map
        g.drawImage(map, 0, 0, this);

        // paint pointers
        g.drawImage(pointer, 50, 75, this);
    }

    // this main is for testing the class but can be used as a reference
    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        SwingPaintDemo mapper = new SwingPaintDemo();
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jf.getContentPane().add(mapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();
    }
}
```

You will need to edit this to load in your images from your file - I wanted to make this self contained and easily runnable so I have just created the images inline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ken. Yes it is a Desktop App. See my comments in post below also. Cheers, Ian

Answer (score 1):

An answer has not been accepted, yet.  So, using your pseudo code as an example, I coded up a quick overlay example using JavaFX 2.  The WebView can easily be replaced with an ImageView using the JPG file you mentioned.

Here is the code:

```
package simple.map.overlay;

import java.io.InputStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleMapOverlay extends Application 
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {               
        WebView mapView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = mapView.getEngine();
        String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Baramerica,+South+Alamo+Street,+San+Antonio,+TX&hl=en&ll=29.416647,-98.488655&spn=0.025196,0.035233&sll=29.416423,-98.489814&sspn=0.006299,0.008808&hq=Baramerica,&hnear=S+Alamo+St,+San+Antonio,+Texas&t=m&z=15";
        url += "&output=embed";
        webEngine.load(url);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(5);
        vBox.getChildren().add(mapView);

        InputStream instream = SimpleMapOverlay.class.getResourceAsStream("beer.png");
        Image beerImage = new Image(instream);        

        instream = SimpleMapOverlay.class.getResourceAsStream("food.jpg");
        Image foodImage = new Image(instream);

        Marker laTunaMarker = new Marker(beerImage, "La Tuna");
        laTunaMarker.setLayoutX(210);
        laTunaMarker.setLayoutY(480);

        Marker rosariosMarker = new Marker(foodImage, "Rosarios");
        rosariosMarker.setLayoutX(360);
        rosariosMarker.setLayoutY(300);

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        root.getChildren().add(laTunaMarker);
        root.getChildren().add(rosariosMarker);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);        

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Map World with Markers!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    class Marker extends Group
    {
        public Marker(Image image, String text)
        {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);            
            Label label = new Label(text);            
            VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
            vbox.getChildren().add(imageView);
            vbox.getChildren().add(label);
            getChildren().add(vbox);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The images need to be in the same directory as the SimpleMapOverlay class, because of the path I passed to #getResourceAsStream().